# Ebean - find parent entities with size of @OneToMany of @ManyToMany = 0

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

My application holds below model class:

```java
public class RetailerUploadUid extends Model {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  public Integer id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "retailer_upl_sku_map", 
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="ret_uid_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="sku_id"))
  public List<Sku> skus;

}
```

The `Sku` class has an id field called `skuId`.

How do I find all `RetailerUploadUid` entities which don't have any child `Skus`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `RetailerUploadUid` class has a Finder, called `find`. Have you tried something like:

```
find.where().eq("skus", null).findList();
```

Or maybe even something like:

```
String query = "find * fetch skus where skus.skuId is null";
Ebean.createQuery(RetailerUploadUid.class, query).findList();
```